# Trying to set up an accordion section on my tumblr page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I've been trying to set this up on my tumblr page for the past 9 hours and nothing I try works. I've googled and googled, tried 20 different methods, and I'm stuck.

I set up a JSfiddle so it's easier to see what I'm going for (and failing at). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/q50as7u0/4/

```
<div class="accordion-section"><a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">About</a>
  <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-1">
    <p>Test Text</p>
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-section-->
<div class="accordion-section"><a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Requirements</a>
  <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-2">
    <p>Test Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-section-->
<div class="accordion-section"><a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">Rules</a>
  <div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-3">
    <p>Test Text 3</p>
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-section-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this guide on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) to set it up.
Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q50as7u0/9/)

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i; 

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

div.panel {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">About</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Requirements</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Rules</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

However this doesn't exactly help your code, so hopefully someone can help you with what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS Fiddle there are a lot of issues.

1. Can't find the CSS for class `open`.
2. Your `close_accordion_section()` function removes class `active` from all the accordions, try and use `href`-attribute and pass that as a param to this 
   function.
3. Here something's ought to be wrong, as either ways you are calling this 
   function which simply closes all the accordions.

```js
 if (jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      close_accordion_section();

      // Add active class to section title
      jQuery(this).addClass('active');
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      jQuery('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
    }
```

Your code is too random to help, please make these changes and then ask again.
Thanks!